# Cannot connect to iCloud after sign-out

Tags: icloud

today I sign out from iCloud from my Macbook and reboot.
After that I tried to sign in again from the System Preferences, but I always receive an error said: "You can't login at this time. Please sign in again."

Nothing worked so I tried to login to apple.com to manage my Apple ID and that worked.

So I tried to login in icloud.com from web and TA-DA! I cannot login there too.

I receive this error log: http://pastebin.com/dseJks18

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Might have to ask Apple, or get someone smarter than me to look at it, but this looks like the start of the problem to me; that looks a long response time to me

```
Tue, 16 Sep 2014 08:02:10 GMT:  DEBUG: <--  Response 4:  0  (489ms),  headers:   body: (empty)
Tue, 16 Sep 2014 08:02:10 GMT:  WARN:  Could not decode JSON: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF
```

Answer form only used to be able to format correctly.

Comment: Yes, I agree and it's the same I'm trying to tell to AppleCare support...but I don't think they are so much "genius"